# Passing data between angular components

Tags: angular, emit

I have component1, which imports component2 and uses it's functions.
this function calls dialog window from component2.

```
export class component1 implements OnInit {
  @Output() testVar= new EventEmitter();

    openDialog(){
    this.testVar.emit(200); 
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Component2, {
```

Now I want somehow send variable to that component. So when second component OnInit it could get my variable, something like

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
 @Input() testVar;

somefunc() {
onUpload(testVar) {
  console.log(testVar) ;
}
```

Can you please write some example or give me the link? Problem is that I want to do this between .ts files without html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig in the `dialog.open(Component2, { data: {testVar:'Hello'}})`

```
 export class Component2 implements OnInit {
      constructor(  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {testVar:string})

     somefunc() { 
         console.log(this.data.testVar) ;
      }
```

Comment: constructor(  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {testVar:string})  > Cannot find name MAT_DIALOG_DATA

Comment: @David: Did you import it? `import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';`